# phonegap navigator.app.exitApp in windows, advice sought

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I have a phonegap app working in both iOS and Android and am planning a release on Windows Phone. I have used navigator.app.exitApp in Android but not in iOS as I heard that Apple would interpret that as a crash.

Is there any such advice for using it in Windows Phone?

Comment: why was this marked down?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't encounter any problems using it, our app is approved and is still in the store. So I would say it's alright to use it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep it in then.